# Rails application works with ip, but not with domain name in Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

In CentOS 7.x I've installed a Rails app which I can access through [ip]:8080. It works using ip.
But when I set the domain name as a server_name (instead of localhost) mydomain.com gives me a 502 Bad Gateway problem. Ip still works.

I already restarted nginx. And the application is running with unicorn_rails. My rails log shows nothing.
PD: This app is from this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5).

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /var/www/my_app/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

> /var/www/my_app/config/unicorn.rb

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/var/www/my_app"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/var/www/my_app/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
#listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

> This is what my /var/log/nginx/error.log shows:

```
2015/02/17 14:06:34 [crit] 14512#0: *375 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.45.678.91, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock:/", host: "mydomain.com"
2015/02/17 14:06:36 [crit] 14512#0: *375 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.45.678.91, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock:/", host: "mydomain.com"
```

A second question, the application only executes when I run `unicorn_rails`, how can I make it run permanently?

Comment: How come you have unicorn running on both port and sock file, check your unicorn settings and make sure it's using a sock file by default, otherwise change your upstream to pass to port 8080

Comment: what do you see after run ``sudo service nginx restart``, may be it help. Also check the file ``/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock``, does it readable and writeable.

Comment: Now that I see, that file is not there. ls shows only those folders:cache  pids  sessions  sockets. Any hint why that sock is not created?

Comment: No, with domain name I don't include the port. It's just mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this previous answer as it might be the solution to your problem: [Nginx cannot find unix socket file with Unicorn (no such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272943/nginx-cannot-find-unix-socket-file-with-unicorn-no-such-file-or-directory)

The tl;dr version is you might need to create your unicorn socket in a different location.  It might be that when you went from being "localhost" to a domain name you are telling the upstream app that you aren't coming from the local filesystem anymore; however, that is conjecture and someone else should chime in.

This post notes that you can't put interprocess communication sockets in /tmp: https://serverfault.com/questions/463993/nginx-unix-domain-socket-error/464025#464025

Answer (score 0):

Seems like requires additional information about your environment:

1) `namei -lm /tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock` - display all permissions of path

2) `ps aux | grep nginx` -  display nginx owner and group

3) `ps axu | grep unicorn` - display unicorn owner and group

4) Provide value of `user` statement from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf